# Allow admin user in aws cognito to sign up normal users when "Only allow administrators to create users" is toggled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, admin

I am using the "amazon-cognito-identity-js" lib to try and perform user signup to my cognito user pool. I have the pool set to "Only allow administrators to create users" because the use case is as followed:

1. We, the admin/devs, creates an admin user for a company in the pool (via the aws cli as we need to set a custom attribute)
2. The admin user logs in to the application (via cognitos hosted UI)
3. The admin user can then create new normal users for their respective company through our application

The admins gets added to an ADMINS group in the pool with necessary roles/policies. Which roles/policies needed is also a bit unknown as of writing.

Today I am trying to do this using the .signup function from amazon-cognito-identity-js, but as expected it gives me an error saying "SignUp is not permitted for this user pool".

How do I let my admin users create/sign-up users to my pool with the available tools I have? Should this be run through lambdas?